# Creating a util class in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a util class for my react app. util classes should be static classes which cannot be instantiated as I know. So, what is the proper way to create a util class in javascript and how we can make it static?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can define a class that contains only `static` methods, it may look something like as follows:

```
class Util {

  static helper1 () {/* */}
  static helper2 () {/* */}

}

export default Util;
```

However, since you don't need a possibility to instantiate an object of the utility class, chances are that you don't really need a class and a simple module that exports utility functions will suite your demand better:

```
const helper1 = () => {/* */};
const helper2 = () => {/* */};

export default {
  helper1,
  helper2
};
```

Answer (score 1):

@anotonku's answer is almost perfect, but a little add-on to the second option - in some `IDE` (it's you, `VSCode`); if you wrap the function in `export default` without a name, it would not be recognised as in suggestions.

And if this bothers you, just export the function directly:

```js
export const helper1 = () => {/* */};
export const helper2 = () => {/* */};
```

It would work as expected.